# how to retrieve values from the database using javascript code?

Tags: java, javascript, mysql, jsp

I m doing a database project using jsp and javascript and back-end using mysql.

In my GUI,there is a page where when i select a particular item in a textbox .the other textboxes should automatically load other values from the database using the value selected from the first textbox.how can i do this using javascript?

I tried using

```
obj1=this.options[this.selectedIndex].myvalue
```

But this did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javascript is a client-side scripting language .You  should use AJAX for access data from Mysql Server.

javascript is used in `AJAX` to connect to databases. So what you need is an `Ajax` call to the server, retrieve values from database.

Refer : http://www.ajaxmatters.com/2006/05/getting-started-with-ajax-using-java-tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

In this case your Javascript is running at the client end (Browser). It has no programmatic access to the server. The DB operations can be performed by your Java code and the results can consumed by the Javascript. So what you need is an Ajax call to the server, retrieve values from database, construct a JSON response and return it to the client.

Comment: how to call a server using ajax..Any tutorials please

Answer (score 0):

use `ajax` to make a server call that will retrieve the values from the database.Its not possible in Javascript alone.

Comment: Can u send me any tutorials or documents or sample codes for this.

Comment: http://www.codecoffee.com/articles/ajax.html and http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is processed by the web browser, and as such doesn't have direct access to your web server as it is done after the user has received the data from your server.

To do as you wish you need to use a server-side language (in your case java as you stated your page is a .jsp)

If you are really dead-set on doing this in Javascript, then node.js may be of assistance, check out http://nodejs.org/ and http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/learning-serverside-javascript-with-node-js/ however seeing as you are using java to generate your pages this is a bit overkill.